# Finding out the keyboard layout

Tags: android, keyboard

Is there a way to find out the current [keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout)?
I.e.: the typical layout is QWERTY but, e.g., Germany usually has QWERTZ, etc.
Also, I've seen some older Android phones without digits row on the main keyboard page.
Is it possible to find out if the current keyboard layout has also digits row? (Digits row without long touch) And potentially other "non standard" things?

Comment: By layout do you mean the language the keyboard uses? For instance "qwertz" is used in the German layout.

Comment: @Yonjuni - I added a clarification into the post. It's really 'keyboard layout'. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to find out current keyboard layout ?

Unless you mean "the keyboard that is visible to the user right this instant", there is no concept of a "current keyboard layout" in Android. A user may have 0-N input method editor implementations available to them, choosing among them as the user sees fit. Plus, depending on circumstances (e.g., `inputType` hints), an input method editor can display different input options.

> Is it possible to find out if the current keyboard layout has there also digits row ?

No.

> And potentially other "nonstandard" things ?

No.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I upvoted but to answer too I use natural language so current keyboard layout is really current keyboard layout - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout.